# How Can I have single project in Maven including EAR , WAR and EJB?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, ear

I am building this application for a client where one project folder with one pom file should consists all the EAR, WAR and EJB.

I found each of its own way in creating the project structure  like http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/guide/Archetype/

How to create my own maven structure for this or are there any available archtype I can use?

Comment: Create a multi-module build which contains of the appropriate modules like mod-ejb, mod-war and mod-ear.

Comment: there is a convention that one pom.xml will give you one artifact (war, ear, ...). Although it is possible to get around it its to messy to even try. The multi module build is the way to go.